# Почему Яндекс не индексирует некоторые страницы сайта?

Tags: seo

Почему Яндекс не индексирует страницы вида site.ru/lechenie-alkogolizma/алкоголизм-и-дипсомания/ при таком файле robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /share42/
Disallow: /wm/
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /component/
```

P.S. для Гугла такая же установка стоит и все ок, страницы такого вида в индексе Гугла. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем причина?!

Ссылка http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/

Answer (score 1):

Попробую ответить: (не 100%).
Первая мысль попадание под фильтр (дублирующий контент), не проверял, насколько уникальный контент, но наверняка стоит не релевантный заголовок:

```
 `<title>Лечение алкоголизма и наркомании - Лечение наркомании в Харькове, лечение алкоголизма в Харькове. Реабилитационный центр "Твоя Перемога"</title>`
```

На странице не нашёл h1.
Страницы в поисковике индексируются при условии, что робот нашел их полезными для выдачи. Постарайтесь переосмыслить заголовки, подумайте, на какой поисковый запрос должна показываться эта страница. Адаптируйте страницу под нужную вам целевую аудиторию.
Настройте перелинковку, создайте файл Sitemap с дополнительной информацией о страницах сайта, подлежащих индексированию.